# Probability specific discussions about the order of events

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

On probabilities, the order is what makes students more confused... And I got some doubts that I would like to discuss with you.

I got a group of 5 dices and 6 distinct numbers. 
It I want 2 groups of 2 dices with the same number (2 pairs), I can do it

$$\binom 52\binom 32\binom 11\binom 62\binom 41$$

Since the 2 pairs are multiplying each other, they are permuting, and then I distribute 2 numbers from 6 to these pairs.

My question is about the full house! (1 pair, 1 triplet)
My way of doing it is incorrect:

$$\binom 52\binom 22\binom 62$$

If in the anterior case, I am considering the order, since I am 2 pairs of the same "bag" of dices, why in this case I am not permuting the pair with the triplet?

Thanks

Comment: Not following your calculation.  For the full house $XXXYY$ there is no symmetry between $X$ and $Y$.  That is, interchanging them gives you a different full house.  For the case of two pair, $XXYYZ$ there is a symmetry (as $YYXXZ$ is the same hand).

Comment: @lulu I need to have XXXYY and YYXXX, like XXYYZ and YYXXZ in the case of the double pairs. If I permute my groups while i'm selecting numbers, it gives me all the correct ways.

Comment: I get that you want the dice to be distinguishable....In that case, the symmetry looks like this "choosing $(D_1,D_2) $ to both be $X$ and then $(D_3,D_4)$ to both be $Y$ is the same as first choosing $(D_3,D_4)$ to be $Y$ and then $(D_1,D_2)$ to be $X$."  That symmetry does not exist for full houses.  So I see the number as $\binom 53 \times \binom 61 \times \binom 51$

Comment: @lulu making binom 52 * binom 32 I am permuting my pairs relatively to fixed places. Pair A - Pair B,  Pair B-Pair A.
My question is, why isn't it the same result on a full house when I do binom 53 * binom 22  ??

Comment: The expression you wrote starts with $\binom 52$, not $\binom 53$.  Of course they are same numerically.  Once you have chosen your three for the triple, you need to tell me the value.  That means you multiply by $6$.  Then I need the value for the other two, so I must multiply by $5$.

Comment: @lulu I obtained the intuitive idea that when I have a group of something, like a bag with objects inside, If I do sub-groups of these objects and I multiply them, it results that they are permuting theirselfs relatively to places. Isn't this correct?

Comment: I don't understand what it means to permute things relative to place.  I think it's clearer to focus on actually building the hands:  the way I understand two pairs:  I first choose a pair, $\binom 52$, then assign a value, $6$.  Then I choose another pair, $\binom 32$ and assign a value, $5$.  then I divide by $2$ to reflect the symmetry I mentioned.  Then I assign a value to the odd man out, $4$.  Thus $\binom 52\times 6\times \binom 32 \times 5 \times \frac 12 \times 4= 1800$, same as you got.

Comment: @lulu yes, that's correct. You can do this way or my way. There are 2 options, or you permute the groups, or you permute the numbers. I mean, you can order the groups of dices and don't order the numbers, or you order the numbers and don't order the dices.  

MY doubt is: say you got a group of 3 people. If you do 3 groups of 1 people, it goes $\binom 31\binom21\binom11$, which is the same of 3! , I do 3 groups of 1 person, I multiply and it gives me all ways orderly. If I do a group of 1 person and another group of 2 persons,I do $\binom31\binom22$ and this should order the groups, but dont

Comment: Ok, but the same reasoning for full houses does not give your result.  I choose the triple, $\binom 53$ and assign a value, $6$, then we assign a value to the remaining pair, $5$.  Thus $\binom 53\times 6\times 5$.  In particular there is no $\frac 12$ nor anything like it.

Comment: @lulu but why doesn't it work as well?

Comment: I don't know what more to say...the difference is that there is a symmetry present in the first that is absent from the second.  That symmetry means you have to take $\binom 62$ to get the values for the pairs, not $6\times 5$.  The full house situation breaks that symmetry so we need to take $6\times 5$.

Comment: Try a simpler problem:  tossing a coin three times, how many ways can you get a pair but not a triple?  The answer of course is six, the cases being $HHT,HTH,THH,TTH,THT,HTT$.  My method:  there are $\binom 32$ ways to pick the pair, $2$ ways to give it a value, then $1$ way to assign the odd man out.  Thus $\binom 32 \times 2\times 1=6$.  Your method gives $\binom 32\times \binom 22=3$.

Comment: @lulu yes Lulu, you are right and I understood you. Can I make 1 more question?